# php group array together based on key value being the same

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have the following array

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id_product_option] => 1
        [id_option] => 1
        [id_product] => 3
        [option_value] => White
        [option_name] => color

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id_product_option] => 2
        [id_option] => 2
        [id_product] => 3
        [option_value] => 9oz
        [option_name] => size

    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id_product_option] => 3
        [id_option] => 1
        [id_product] => 3
        [option_value] => Blue
        [option_name] => color

    )

)
```

What i need to do is loop through it and find the ones where the id_option values match and group them into a new array that should look like

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id_product_option] => 1
            [id_option] => 1
            [id_product] => 3
            [option_value] => White
            [additional_cost] => 0
            [is_active] => 1
            [created_on] => 2014-11-15 01:29:35
            [option_name] => color
            [option_text] => Color
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id_product_option] => 3
            [id_option] => 1
            [id_product] => 3
            [option_value] => Blue
            [additional_cost] => 0
            [is_active] => 1
            [created_on] => 2014-11-15 01:29:35
            [option_name] => color
            [option_text] => Color
        )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id_product_option] => 2
        [id_option] => 2
        [id_product] => 3
        [option_value] => 9oz
        [additional_cost] => 0
        [is_active] => 1
        [created_on] => 2014-11-15 01:29:35
        [option_name] => size
        [option_text] => Size
    )


)
```

where the options with id_option 1 are grouped together

I tried the following but no luck

```
    $groupOptions = array();
    $prev = "";
    foreach($productOptions as $key=>$options) {
        $id_option = $options['id_option'];

        if($id_option != $prev) {
            $groupOptions[] = $productOptions[$key];
        }

        $prev = $id_option;
    }
```

Comment: Can you share what you have tried?

Comment: Why are you marking this down i dont understand. Better if you just dont say anything. This place is meant to help people not just think a question is stupid and mark it down

Comment: I don't know who down-voted your question, but it was probably before you had shared what you had tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use that id_option as the key in your new array, otherwise you're stuck having to hunt through the new array to find where the matching items are, which you're ALREADY doing in the first loop

```
$newarray = array();
foreach($oldarray as $item) {
   $newarray[$item['id_option']][] = $item;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tested with you example and seems to work fine :

```
$notFactored; # you should provide here your input array
$factored = array();
foreach($notFactored as $nf) {
    $found = FALSE;
    foreach($factored as &$f) { # passed by address !
        if(!empty($f[0]) && $nf['id_option'] == $f[0]['id_option']) {
            $f[] = $nf;
            $found = TRUE;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(!$found) {
        $factored[count($factored)][] = $nf;
    }
}
print 'my factored array : ' . print_r($factored);
```

Hope that Helps :)